# Do Maxwell's equations contain any information on the time evolution of the current density $J$?

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, maxwell-equations, time-evolution

The answers to [Can the Lorentz force expression be derived from Maxwell's equations?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20477/) make clear that Maxwell's equations contain only information on the evolution of the fields, and not their effects upon charges; the Lorentz force equation is an added equation.

Does this imply that any arbitrary time evolution of a current density can be defined beforehand, and the corresponding fields always found that satisfy Maxwell's equations?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maxwell's equations place a constraint on the current, namely that it be conserved. To see this, take the divergence of Ampere's law for
$$0 = \mu_0 \nabla \cdot \mathbf{J} + \mu_0 \epsilon_0 \nabla \cdot \frac{\partial \mathbf{E}}{\partial t}$$
which is equivalent to
$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{J} = - \epsilon_0 \frac{\partial}{\partial t} (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{E}) = - \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}.$$
This is precisely the statement of charge conservation. If you plug in a $\rho(\mathbf{r}, t)$ and $\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{r}, t)$ that aren't conserved, then the equations will have no solutions at all.

Comment: This is what concerns me: Maxwell's equations doesn't directly contain the information, but it's there by manipulating the equations as you've done. Another example, IMO, is the derivation of Poynting's theorem which appears to place a constraint on $J$ via $\vec J\cdot\vec E$.

Comment: @Physikslover I don't see how that's a concern, though. The equations themselves provide some constraints on what currents are valid, but don't say much else. What's wrong with that?

Comment: Noting wrong with that. My concern is that some are quick to jump to the conclusion that Maxwell's equations don't directly say anything about their time evolution; yet it's there buried within them, if one looks closely. You've given one example, whereas I believe there's additional information.

Answer (score 0):

> Does this imply that any arbitrary time evolution of current density can be defined beforehand, and the corresponding fields always found that satisfy Maxwell's equations?

Yes, given a charge density $\rho(\mathbf r,t)$ and a current density $\mathbf J(\mathbf r,t)$, you can find fields $\mathbf E(\mathbf r,t)$ and $\mathbf B(\mathbf r,t)$ satisfying Maxwell’s equations.

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%C3%A9nard%E2%80%93Wiechert_potential#Derivation) for the integrals giving the scalar potential $\varphi$ and vector potential $\mathbf A$ that solve the nonhomogeneous wave equations with sources $\rho$ and $\mathbf J$. The fields derived from these potentials will satisfy Maxwell’s equations.

One way to think about this is that an arbitrary charge and current density can be considered a swarm of moving point charges. The fields of an arbitrarily moving point charge is known, based on the Liénard-Wiechert potentials. The fields of the swarm are simply the superposition of the fields of all the point charges, by the linearity of Maxwell’s equations.

ADDENDUM: As @knzhou points out in another answer, the $\rho$ and $\mathbf J$ can’t be completely arbitrary. They have to satisfy the physical constraint of current conservation, $\partial\rho/\partial t+\nabla\cdot\mathbf J=0$.