# Application of Kirchhoff's laws in circuits with inductors

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, conservation-laws, electromagnetic-induction

As we know, the [Kirchhoff circuit laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws) are applicable for conservative electric fields. Now it is applicable for circuits where inductors are present but the field there is not [conservative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field).

So how are the  Kirchhoff's laws  applicable there?

Comment: This is an excellent question.

Comment: Walter Lewin explains this by himself https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cZN0AyNR4Kw

Comment: And the electroboom vs lewin controversy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, with inductors, we use the [complex impedance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_impedance#Complex_voltage_and_current), $Z=i\omega L$ with current frequency $\omega$ and inductance $L$, for the voltage:
$$
V_{ind}=IZ,\quad V_{rms}=I_{rms}|Z|
$$
where the left equation is the voltage of the inductor and the right equation the root-mean-square.

Surely, however, what goes on **inside** the inductor doesn't matter, it only is only the voltage drop *across* the inductor that actually matters with Kirchoff's voltage law. Kirchoff's current law, on the other hand, states that the current across a complete circuit is zero because otherwise a charge builds up, so again the non-conservative field is irrelevant.

[Professor Lewin (MIT) explains](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eqjl-qRy71w) that if we have a magnetic potential driving a circuit, rather than a constant voltage source, the Kirchoff voltage law does not come up with the same answer. This is based on a *different* definition of Kirchoff's law than what is normally taught. What Lewin means, of course, is that 
$$
\oint\mathbf E\cdot d\mathbf l=0\tag{1}
$$
He writes this on the board integrating from points $D$ to $A$ on a circuit board going to the left & going to the right, the two directions are not equal. However, most textbooks use the formulation,

> *sum of voltage drops around a loop is equal to the sum of emf around a loop*

which is more equivalent to
$$
\oint\mathbf E\cdot d\mathbf l=-\frac{d\phi}{dt}\tag{2}
$$
which is really [Faraday's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday's_law_of_induction) that *always* works.

With definition (1) & using Professor Lewin's example, we have that the net voltage is 1V (as he described) being driven by an emf of 1 V; all is well with Kirchoff's laws indeed.

Comment: ok leave inductors.So is it true that KVL requires conservative field?

Comment: We wouldn't be able to model circuits with inductors if KVL/KCL required conservative fields.

Comment: @KyleKanos The scalar potential is only defined for conservative forces.  See my post.

Comment: @user3814483: Of course conservative forces lead to scalar potentials, but this fact is irrelevant since circuit analysis only requires counting the *voltage drop **across*** the component.

Comment: @KyleKanos Good luck applying KVL in microwave circuits.  There's its kludgy at best and people apply them infinitesimally, when in fact the exact solutions are wave equations.

Comment: @user3814483: You mean [like this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_balance)? Kirchoff's laws hold on the circuit *always* (if it didn't current or voltage would build up at some node, which cannot happen), the *methods* by which you satisfy it may vary (i.e., using Newton iteration instead of simple sums), but it holds always.

Comment: @KyleKanos No, not like that. I'm just trying to remind you not to be so cavalier, and recall that KVL only holds if each and every component is be modeled as a lumped element.  Non-conservative fields can create situations where this is not the case.  In other words, I'm talking about this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1bUWcy8HwpM, in case you somehow missed it.

Comment: @user3814483: I don't see how Lewin's lecture is related to the discussion on hand. OP's problem is that the field **inside** the inductor is non-conservative but we can still use Kirchoff's laws for the circuit; the reason is because the voltage drop across the inductor doesn't rely on what happens inside. Doing loop analysis with changing magnetic fields is entirely irrelevant for OPs problem.

Comment: @KyleKanos It's not related to the OPs problem (in my post I addressed the OPs problem AND covered all of this). My original comment to you was in response to what you said to soumyadeep regarding the more general issue.

Comment: @soumyadeep Generally (you said "leave inductors..."), to use KVL in a circuit you need to (1) Not have any nonconservative fields OR (2) abstract-away non-conservative fields using Maxwell's equations by modeling them as lumped elements.  I explained this in my original answer.  As in the link in my previous comment, you can't always do (2) in the presence of nonconservative fields.

Comment: @user3814483: please see my update with regards to your discussion.

Comment: @KyleKanos Good, we're on the same page!  Lewin also argues that the latter definition is incorrect, but that's a different story.  This being Physics SE I prefer the former definition, but I understand why EE's and hence most of the literature go with the latter.

Comment: @user3814483: It looks to me that the two definitions are actually different. Lewin assumes the position that Kirchoff requires a zero on the RHS while the more common definition I cite does not necessarily assume this.

Comment: @KyleKanos Right, they are different, and the RHS = 0 comes from d/dt(Phi) = 0 (conservative fields).  I think the saving grace in the second definition is the term "EMF" - which is akin to taking all the non-conservative stuff and applying Maxwell separately to produce and effective voltage.  That was my motivation for saying a bit earlier - either make sure d/dt(Phi) = 0 (conservative everywhere) or abstract away non-conservative fields into an EMF (e.g., inductor).

Comment: @KyleKanos Well sorry i cannot watch Proffesor  Lewin's lecture right now.But anyway ,I cannot understand why the limits of the integral are different i.e a and b.

Comment: @soumyadeep: The integration limits are different because of the set-up that Prof. Lewin describes; I've updated the answer to reflect the more correct formulation (i.e., closed integrals).

Answer (score 1):

Kirchhoff's laws follow from the conservation of charge and energy in a circuit. Neither is violated in non-conservative fields. A circuit description of such a field would merely act like an active source in a circuit, no different from a battery, which also supplies net energy. For the purposes of circuit analysis the source of that net energy is usually irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

According to Stoke's theorem,
$$\oint_C\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{l}=-\int_S\partial_t\vec{B}\cdot d\vec{S}=-\frac{d\Phi}{dt}.$$
If a circuit is of laboratory size and $\partial_t \vec{B}$ not too large, then the integral of $\vec{E}$ around the circuit $C$ is approximately zero. This is Kirchhoff's circuit law (KVL). Kirchhoff's current law (KCL) is simpler: it is merely charge conservation applied at a node and then time differentiated.

Answer (score 0):

KVL is essentially a statement of energy conservation, while KCL follows from conservation of charge.  KVL, as the name implies, depends on a definition of voltage (scalar potential).  This definition is only possible when the electric fields are conservative such that $\nabla \times E = 0$, so that we can define $E = -\nabla V$.

In an inductor, this is clearly not the case because we have time-varying magnetic fields (e.g., even for a DC circuit there's a transient during turn-on).  In general, for such situations we must turn to Maxwell's equations for a solution.

However, since *most* of the circuit does not violate this condition, we can treat the remainder of the circuit using KVL, and remedy the inductor by introducing the notion of a back EMF.  The back EMF comes from an independent application of Maxwell's equations to the inductor.

There are situations where non-conservative fields cannot be treated in a lumped fashion.  This includes for example RF transmission lines in a circuit.  In such situations, KVL breaks down and we have to resort to Maxwell's equations for solutions.