# Voltage about potential difference

Tags: electricity, potential, voltage, definition

Can someone explain to me all about potential difference. It is basically taught when teaching about voltage but I want to know all about potential difference.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well, its about the concentration difference in electricity. It's basically the amount of change in potential energy when a unit charge goes from one position to another.

Answer (score 3):

Voltage *is* the potential difference between two points.

Comment: Thanks it helped

Comment: Voltage is an imprecise term that can refer to either potential difference or to electromotive force.

Comment: @ThePhoton good point.