# Potential Difference and Electrical Potential

Tags: potential, voltage, definition

What is the difference between Electrical Potential and Potential Difference?

Please try to explain in layman language

Any response would be apriciated

Comment: Possible  duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15402/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

Think of electrical potential and potential difference like a hill and a slope. Imagine you're standing on top of a hill. The height of the hill represents the electrical potential. It's like how much "push" or "pull" electric charges feel at that spot. If the hill is really high, there's a lot of potential energy for things to roll down or move around.

Now, imagine there's another hill nearby, but it's lower. The difference in height between these two hills is the potential difference. It's like the "drop" between them. If you were to roll a ball from the top of one hill to the other, it would go down because of the height difference – just like how electric charges flow from a higher potential to a lower potential because of this difference.

So, in simpler terms:

Electrical Potential: This is like the height of a hill. It tells us how much "push" or "pull" electric charges feel at a certain spot.

Potential Difference: This is like the difference in height between two hills. It's the "drop" or "slope" that causes electric charges to move from one place to another.

In electrical terms, potential difference is what makes electric charges flow through things like wires, and electrical potential is what describes how strong that push or pull is at different points.