# What is the difference between: “Electric Potential”, “Electric Potential Energy”, “Electric Potential Difference”, and lastly, “Voltage”?

Tags: energy, electric-circuits, electric-current, potential, voltage

Please provide very simple and specific examples/explanations when answering. Some have described Electric Potential as “work done per unit of charge”, but what exactly does “per unit of charge” mean? Isn’t that the same as Eletric Potential energy?

Comment: First define potential energy, that would be the energy due to source and test particle interaction. That is something is interacting with something. Now just forget about the test particle, make it of charge unity, then all are are left with is the field of the source that is the potential field. Potential difference would be just the value of potential at one point with respect to another point(which is at noon zero potential), it's a relative field.

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/799242/2451 Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15402/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Electric potential energy = Potential energy of one charge, multiplied by the number of charges. Electric potential at some point = Potential energy of one charge at that point. Electric potential difference = Difference of potentials between two points. Voltage = Same as potential difference. To get examples, replace "one charge" by "one electron". To be more correct, replace "one charge" by "one unit of charge".