# Would it be right to say that “Electric Potential” = the potential energy of an individual unit of charge at a certain point in a electric field?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, potential-energy, voltage

Any replies from people who actually understand the topic (better than me, to say the least lol) and are able to clarify the topic (unlike my teacher), are highly appreciated and encouraged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your statement is only true if the individual particle carries a unit charge. Change In Electric Potential is defined as the change in electric potential energy per unit charge.Taking the potential(and potential energy) to be 0 at infinity the potential energy and potential are related by U=qV where u is the potential energy, V is the potential. U=V is only true when q=1.

PS: electric potential is defined as the scalar potential of the electric field vector,ie. E=-grad(V).

Comment: Thank you for the response! What I’m most confused about is what exactly is meant by “infinity”? What point is that?

Comment: The point at infinity means a point very faaar away from the charge distribution, so far that we can actually treat the electric field there to be 0, and potential consequently to be 0.